# arResult в битрикс, или вывод данных в других компонентах

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

дамы и господа, суть моей проблемы такова:
1)в карточке товара есть блок видео о товаре, видео выводится из
`'$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PRODUCT_VIDEO_ID"]["VALUE"]'` (в нем хранится ссылка на видео) все это действо происходит в шаблоне компонента `bitrix:catalog.element`.

Передо мной встала задача поместить маленькую иконку о наличии видео у товара, как бы я не выворачивался на изнанку переменная не хочет выбираться в другой компонент, а именно в `custom:mc.catalog.section`.

Перепробовал все(!) варианты которые были в моей голове, гуглил, шаманил, молился богам, стучал в бубен, нервно хватался за волосы, но вывести переменную у меня не получилось из одного компонента в другой.

По логике, есть и другие варианты, например в шаблоне компонента `bitrix:catalog.element` заставить писать эту переменную, например, в одну строку с `ID` товара, а затем в компоненте `custom:mc.catalog.section` читать этот файл, и если он видит, что у компонента с таким-то `ID` есть еще и видео, то вывести иконку...

Это для моего пытливого разума слишком сложно(сказались тонны бессонных ночей...)

Прошу прощения, что не предоставил код, приходится объяснять "на пальцах", всю нужную информацию я могу предоставить, очень прошу помочь!!!))

Answer (score 0):

Битрикс это сложный инструмент и его стоит прежде изучить. в вашем случае используется самодельный компонент custom:mc.catalog.section как он устроен и что умеет ни кто здесь не знает. По этому ответ из расчета на штатный [bitrix:catalog.section](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/catalog/catalog_section.php)  Если прочитать документацию, то можно заметить несколько параметров PROPERTY_CODE, PROPERTY_CODE_MOBILE, OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE.  Т.е. если вы в дин из этих массивов добавите PRODUCT_VIDEO_ID, то получите в шаблоне этого компонента искомое. Для варианта PROPERTY_CODE ищите следующим образом: Наверняка у вас в шаблоне есть подобная конструкция

```
<? foreach ($aResult['ITEMS'] as $arItem):?>
....
<? endforeach ?>
```

Так вот и ищите искомое в $arItem.  (вероятно $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]['PRODUCT_VIDEO_ID'])

Comment: есть единственное- "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array();

Comment: Но есть параметр подобный PROPERTY_CODE ? Если есть задано значение? Иначе надо смотреть код вашего компонента и дорабатывать

Comment: итог-есть массив arResult в нужном мне компоненте, и массив item, ни в одном, ни в другом нет элемента ["PROPERTIES"]["PRODUCT_VIDEO_ID"]["VALUE"], вот и понимаю я, что у каждого компонента arResult свой, но что мне делать, если мне нужно (вынь и выложи) получить чертов элемент ?

Comment: Посмотреть как это сделано в штатном и повторить. У вас вкомпоненте должно быть нечто типа CIBlockElement::GetList (а может быть и новое АПИ испоьзуется)... Далее цикл по полученной выборке . Внутри получение свойств при помощи GetProperties (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/_cibelement/getproperties.php)  там по ссылке есть пример

Comment: а какой вид имеет новое АПИ? потому что в компоненте, в котором работает PRODUCT_VIDEO_ID используеться только GetEditAreaId($arResult["ID"])

Comment: Сдается вы смотрите шаблон компонента (template.php), а не компонент (component.php или class.php). Запрос элементов может быть выполнен двумя способами:
CIblockElement::GetList() - это по старому; \Bitrix\Iblock\ElementTable::getList() - по новому

Если способ иной, например: $DB->query или вообще mysql_query -   то же такое встречал. Но тут уже вам вообще трудно будет подсказывать, т.к. модуль, в этом случае, реализовывался кем то с очень низкой квалификацией.

Comment: слава богу, там нет прямых запросов к базе данных, видел директивный вид неоднократно в кастомных компонентах, значит, там нужно ковырять...спасибо...

Answer (score 0):

Если компонент не предоставляет нужных данных в $arResult, то эти данные можно получить самостоятельно, добавив в шаблон файл result_modifier.php. В этом файле сделать нужные запросы и модифицировать $arResult.

Примерно так:

```php
foreach($arResult['ITEMS'] as &$item){
    $row = CIBlockElement::GetList([], [
         'IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
         'ID' => $item['ID']
       ],
       false,
       false,
       ['IBLOCK_ID', 'ID', 'PROPERTY_PRODUCT_VIDEO_ID']
    )->Fetch();
    $item['PROPERTIES']['PRODUCT_VIDEO_ID']['VALUE'] = $row['PROPERTY_PRODUCT_VIDEO_ID_VALUE'];
}
```